# Find the closest element with absolute position

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a simple way to find the closest element with absolute position.

```
/*These have come dynamically with jquery*/
  <div class="validationWarning with-triangle::after">Validation Alert</div>


<input id="relative1" type="text" required/>
<input id="relative2" type="text" required/>
<input id="relative3" type="text" required/>
<input id="relative4" type="text" required/>
<input id="relative5" type="text" required/>
<input id="relative6" type="text" required/>
<input id="relative7" type="text" required/>
```

I have been using `el.getBoundingClientRect()` to position the absolute element to each input:

```
//...is on.submit
    $("#orderForm :input").each(function(){
     var inputID = $(this).attr("id"); 


    var checking = $(this).val(); 

     if(checking == "")
        {
            var elss = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect();
            var leftPos = elss.left + window.scrollX;
            var toptPos = elss.top + window.scrollY;
            $(".validationWarning").css({top: toptPos+40, left: leftPos, display: 'block'});
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+inputID).offset().top-18}, 500);

            return false; 
        }
```

Now I need to fadeout the absolute alert div when the closest input is in `focus`

Comment: may be $(element).find('element').css('position')

Comment: `var absPos = $("div").filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('position') == 'absolute';
});` Start from there maybe?

Comment: That's good enogh to get start eventhough will need to write out +/- 10 lines of code. (I wiss it would not be more than 5 lines) Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Since you already have some script to position each element to the inputs, you might consider just using .wrap() around your inputs and then appending the validation warning to that new element. Then if you want the validation message, all you have to do is grab the input and use .next() to get the corresponding message. Should be easier than dealing with screen positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will accomplish what you're looking for.

In your current code, when you position the element, do the following:

```
if(checking == "")
{
    ...

    $(this).after($(".validationWarning")); //ADD THIS LINE

    return false; 
}
```

This will grab the existing validation warning and *move* it in the DOM immediately after your input. It shouldn't break your layout because you're absolutely positioning the element. Visibly the element will be where you put it, but as far as the browser is concerned, it's the element immediately after your input.

This means that you can add an event handler and do this:

```
$(":input").on("focus", function() {
    $(this).next(".validationWarning").fadeOut();
});
```

When your input is focused, you'll grab the element immediately following the focused input (if it matches the `.validationWarning` selector) and fade it out.

More info about `.after()` in the jQuery docs http://api.jquery.com/after

Comment: I never want to say perfect to any code. But this is just that. Thank you, Joel.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of finding the closest, you can add custom data attribute to error message tooltip. And the value can be ID attribute of the input textbox. Like:

```
$("#orderForm :input").each(function(){
 var inputID = $(this).attr("id"); 


var checking = $(this).val(); 

 if(checking == "")
    {
        var elss = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        var leftPos = elss.left + window.scrollX;
        var toptPos = elss.top + window.scrollY;
        $(".validationWarning").data('targetID', inputID);
        $(".validationWarning").css({top: toptPos+40, left: leftPos, display: 'block'});
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+inputID).offset().top-18}, 500);

        return false; 
    }
```

And then onfocus of input text, you can find the appropriate error tooltip element like:

```
var inputID = $(this).attr('id');
$("div[data-targetID='" + inputID + "']");
```